# Trying to send CSS in HTML email over Outlook with JavaMail

Tags: java, html, css, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an HTML email by building a string and passing it as a parameter my mail method:

```
// Build string to send as email message
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        buf.append("<html>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<table>" +
                "<tr style=\"background-color: #8C0000; color: #fff; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;\">" +
                "<th style=\"padding: 10px;\">Assigned Group</th>" +
                "<th style=\"padding: 10px;\">Incident Type</th>" +
                "<th style=\"padding: 10px;\">Status</th>" +
                "<th style=\"padding: 10px;\">Assignee</th>" +
                "<th style=\"padding: 10px;\">Incident Number</th>" +
                "<th style=\"padding: 10px;\">Priority</th>" +
                "<th style=\"padding: 10px;\">Summary</th>" +
                "</tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < incidentNumberList.size(); i++) {
            buf.append("<tr style=\"font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;\"><td style=\"padding: 10px;\">")
                    .append(assignedGroup)
                    .append("</td><td style=\"padding: 10px;\">")
                    .append(incidentTypeList.get(i))
                    .append("</td><td style=\"padding: 10px;\">")
                    .append(statusList.get(i))
                    .append("</td><td style=\"padding: 10px;\">")
                    .append(assigneeNameList.get(i))
                    .append("</td><td style=\"padding: 10px;\">")
                    .append(incidentNumberList.get(i))
                    .append("</td><td style=\"padding: 10px;\">")
                    .append(priorityList.get(i))
                    .append("</td><td style=\"padding: 10px;\">")
                    .append(summaryList.get(i))
                    .append("</td></tr>");
        }
        buf.append("</table>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>");
        String emailMessage = buf.toString();

        // Send an email to the manager of the Assigned Group
        sendManagerEmail(emailMessage);
```

Email method:

```
private static void sendManagerEmail(String emailMessage) {
        final String username = "user";
        final String password = "pass123";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        if (ENCRYPT) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        } else {
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
        }
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "internetsmtp.example.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "internetsmtp.example.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        // SSL
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("martin@example.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("martin@example.com"));
            message.setSubject("Tickets — Attention Needed");
            message.setContent(emailMessage
                    , "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

The important line here is `message.setContent(emailMessage
                    , "text/html; charset=utf-8");` The string of HTML code I sent into this method comprises the body of the message content.

The email comes formatted with the table but not the CSS, which makes it fairly ugly. Is there anything I can do here to display the CSS? I assumed that building the style directly into the html tags would be enough.

Comment: Can you please post the html of the email ?

Comment: The HTML of the email is visible above. It's being built as a string then passed into the mail method. @AdrienQUINT

Comment: Yep, but i would like to see how is the final render (the email).

Comment: I see. I can't exactly show you because of the content but basically none of the CSS is applied. The tables are applied but no styling. I'm sure you can imagine based on the CSS above.

Comment: Are the "style" attributes present on the DOM elements ?

Comment: The emails are being retrieved in Outlook (version 14). There isn't a DOM I don't think.

Comment: It seems that there is a way to see the source : (at least in outlook 2010) https://superuser.com/questions/389717/how-do-i-view-source-in-outlook-2010

Comment: Sorry! Problem solved. The emails are being sent to my Junk Mail. But as soon as I put them in Inbox the HTML is rendered.

Comment: Hahaha shame on you :p

Comment: :P At least someone else will know not to debug with Junk mails.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is correct, but make sure to encrypt your emails with TLS (http://blog.redturtle.it/2011/10/28/using-javamail-with-tls) so that they do not end up in Junk Mail. Junk emails typically do not render HTML. If you are having trouble setting up TLS then debug by moving the mail from Junk to Inbox to see the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you try embeding the CSS in the actual html?
`<style>css code</style>`